# Как сделать контрол перемещаемый мышкой

Tags: wpf

Есть такой контрол:

```
public class DrawCanvasTextBox : Canvas
    {
        public DrawCanvasTextBox()
        {
            Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gray;

        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
        }
    }
```

Вот что в него надо добавить, что бы его можно было перемещать мышкой? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

используйте метод [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx). Пример [здесь](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/dodragdrop/).

Comment: Неет, мне нужно положение контрола менять.